# Regex matching any successive lines starting with dash

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
- Give on result
- Second new text
- The third text

Another paragraph without list.

-New list here
```

I need a regex that matches all successive lines starts with dash `-` so, it should returns two matches, i.e the first 3 lines and the last line. I have tried `/(-(.*)\n\s*\n)*/gum` but it just matches the last line of the the first three lines `The third text` and [this is a demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

```
(-(.*))(\n-(.*))*
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/tQ1eS1/1)

Your regex has two new lines (`\n\s*\n`).